# Is the "Snake Position" halal for my wife?

Tags: sex, intercourse

A sex position called "Snake position" is famous. It refers to, the woman will lay straight on bed on her stomach and the man will approach her from behind.

But my question is, in a Hadith there is a restriction on laying on stomach.

So is this position Halal for my wife?

Answer (score -3):

This is probably not halal for your wife, and sleeping on your stomach can cause pain to your backbone.

It is also how the people of hell lie.

Comment: You got evidence to back up this answer?